# Preventing window from resizing vertically from a certain point and downwards

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, resize

I'm creating a site using bootstrap.

I would like to prevent the window from resizing at all from a certain point and downwards.

I currently have it set at:

```
html, body{

 min-width: 300px;
 max-width: 3000px;
 min-height: 550px;
 max-height: 1500px;

}
```

seems to work perfectly for the width, once the window reaches 300px in width, the width of the window locks and cannot be scaled down any further.

for some reason though, it will not work for the height, no matter what parameters and dimensions I set, I can fully scale the height of it.

Not sure how to work around this so that once the window reaches 550px of height, the height also locks and cannot be scaled down any further.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

thats not an an issue, actually what you are saying, is device width not the document or window width, if you are worried about responsiveness, no device exist on the world whose height can be changed, atleast i dont know,

this should not be an issue, you are scaling the browser's(device) height and width , but the actual window sizing is working same like the width, ,,

i mean that css code is working fine, but you cannot notice that,

Answer (score 0):

It's because max-height overrides height, but min-height always overrides max-height. So you can't use them in the way you intend.

You need to target with media queries:

```
body { height:550px }
@media (min-height: 550px) { body {height: 100vh }}
@media (min-height: 1500px) { body { height: 1500px }}
```